# Weird syntax or property declaration

Tags: objective-c

I'm a bit confused of following syntax:

```
@property (nonatomic, getter = isFailed) BOOL failed; // Return Yes if image failed to be downloaded
```

Especially line `getter = isFailed`.

If i understand correct, getter is simple method like below:

```
-(BOOL)failed{
   return _failed;
}
```

What does that mean then?

Comment: The getter should be `- (BOOL)isFailed {...}`, but if all it's doing is returning the instance variable you should probably let it be synthesized anyway.

Comment: @Kevin, you mean it simple define line when compiler look for getter? If there wasn't such line getter = isFailed, my getter statement would be correct?

Comment: Yes, `getter =` tells the compiler which method name to look for, and if there weren't a `getter = ` your code would be fine.

Comment: @Kevin you might want to add your answer to that topic so i can mark it as correct. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getter =` syntax tells the compiler what method to call for a property access; without it, it defaults to the property's name. So your example code would work if the declaration didn't have `getter =`, but with it you need to use

```
- (BOOL)isFailed {
    return _failed
}
```